# Random IPs in ARP/RARP table with the same mac address?

Tags: network

I was looking at my router settings and saw a bunch of IPs with the same mac address in the ARP/RARP table. The GEOlocation of them all ranges across my country, any ideas to why they are there? Should I be concerned?
It's a Cisco router

```
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.67.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 24.70.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 104.204.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 108.63.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 162.208.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 172.103.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 184.68.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 184.68.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
 184.68.x 64:9E:F3:66:07:x
```

Comment: That's the MAC of the router in the next hop to the Internet (like your ISP). In fact, it could be the MAC of your router (the MAC is from a Cisco device).

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a home router and you've never looked in the ARP table before?

Comment: Yes it's a home router and yes.     Sorry if it's blatantly obvious to what it is, Some of the IPs are from different ISPs but still the same mac address? Should I be at all concerned?        It is not the MAC of my router

Answer (score 3):

It is actually expected that they would all have the same MAC address - MAC addresses do not survive the hop from router to router, so what you are seeing is likely the MAC address of your ISP's router (the closest MAC to your router).

Comment: So what does it mean that these random IPs are in my ARP/RARP table?

Comment: Those are IP addresses you have connected to - for various websites etc

Comment: So even after I've closed the website, they'll still be in there?

Comment: @user6294329 will they still be in the log? Yes.

Comment: so it's not at all suspicious?

Comment: @user6294329 not only is it not suspicious, it is expected. :) Perfectly normal operation.